# How to use iphone x size in xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-x

I only can build an iPhone x simulator but I can't develop iPhone x size in Xcode.
There only can user iPhone 11, iPhone 8, iPhone 4, and iPad size.
I using Xcode 11.4.1 Ios and swift 4.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone11 Pro and iPhoneX have the same dimension.